# they gave you only one mistake(meaning)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I thought I was something special until I jumped from a tower during training and dislocated my right shoulder. I had landed wrong, and they gave you only one mistake. They cut me from the team.

I was reading *[The Irishman](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=kipLDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=I%20had%20landed%20wrong%20and%20they%20gave%20you%20only%20one%20mistake%20the%20Irishman&source=bl&ots=UeSsh6OAQO&sig=ACfU3U2MUH2P3LDj9jzS5-D2un1NiqF3gg&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGwc-l_MvnAhWqGqYKHcSWB7EQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=I%20had%20landed%20wrong%20and%20they%20gave%20you%20only%20one%20mistake%20the%20Irishman&f=false)*. I have no idea what "they gave you only one mistake" means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that they allow people to make mistakes only once.

In the excerpt, he says he landed a jump wrong. As he made this one mistake, he reached his quota of mistakes, and was cut from the team (hence the *"... they gave you only one mistake"* part).